# What is Kafka connect runtime?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

Reading about Kafka connect, it is defined as a runtime which executes tasks.

What exactly it means to say that Kafka connect(or any other piece of software for that matter) is a runtime? And how does it impact its relationship with other parts of the kafka connect architecture , like connectors, converters, or kafka itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the kafka ecosystem , where kafka is a source or a target , Kafka connect provides a framework and a runtime (to execute the code) to implement and operate source and sink connectors.

Source connectors provide a mechanism of reading from an external source and streaming data into Kafka. A very popular source connector is Debezium (streams CDC changes from database tables to Kafka) or it could be a target sink system that can read messages from Kafka and land them on a different database (say elasticsearch , S3 etc.)

One way to think of it is quite similar to a container like Tomcat , a KC runtime provides a common framework for Kafka applications (like tomcat provides for servlets and similar web-apps). It provides mechanisms to operate this in standalone or in clustered modes facilitating interactions with Kafka (offset management for example comes to mind). It provides management API's (connector status , stopping , starting, registering connectors for example)

P.S : wanted to write this as a comment , turned out long in the end :)